# Can you unlock steam achievements in Stardew Valley Multiplayer?

Tags: achievements, stardew-valley

If I start a new coop game can I earn achievements like I would in a singleplayer game? Is that progress shared between all players?

Comment: Will have to double check with the steam achievements, but I know that non-host players can get the in-game achievements. Whenever a player gets one it will show a notification fro everyone, it will also unlock the corresponding hat in the hat shop.

Comment: I was under the impression that beta versions of games don't count towards steam achivements at all. The bottom answers condradict that, however. So I'm conflicted

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping for something more authoritative or my coop companion to earn some achievements to confirm at least guests can unlock them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to confirm that achievements are unlocked for both the host and any farm hands. A friend and I were able to unlock the "Cowpoke - Earn 50,000g" achievement while playing a co-op farm.

Comment: I'm happy to accept someone else's answer if they find a more authoritative source.

Answer (score 3):

I can personally say that i've got steam achievements whilst in a multiplayer session I wasn't hosting. I don't believe they are tracked between all players though.

I got the achievement for catching a certain number of types of fish.

Comment: With conflicting answers, I think it is best if you find some reference or other supporting information. Perhaps a Dev tweet or screen shot.

Comment: I can confirm this: I got "living large" for having my first maximum upgraded house, and it was as a guest in multiplayer mode in the beta version of the game.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get "personal" achievments like catching fish, but the host gets achievemnts like upgrade the house or total money earned.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, only the host can get achievements in a co-op game. The other players will not get achievements; but I am unsure if their actions will trigger acheivements for the host.

Comment: With conflicting answers, I think it is best if you find some reference or other supporting information. Perhaps a Dev tweet or screen shot.